# How to handle OpenGL resources in C#?

Tags: c#, opengl, resources, idisposable

I'm making a Mesh class in C# as seen in my previous question. It does have a handle to some OpenGL resources which need to be freed. In C++ this is solved with a destructor, but how do I achieve something like that in C#? I've heard about IDisposable, but it seems like I then either need to call dispose on it or wrap the existence of an object with a using statement, neither of which are as convenient as the C++ way. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Disposing of an object that utilizes unmanaged resources is the standard approach in C#. Wrapping all of the code that references that object in a using statement, like you said, is a great way to do it.

Comment: That would be one of the reasons why games (engines) aren't written in C#.

Comment: That's absolutely nothing to do with it Bartek.  The correct paradigm to use for disposal of unmanaged resources is the IDisposable pattern.   If you don't know this, you should read up on it because it's quite fundamental given that the CLR *has no choice* but to use unmanaged resources at times.  It's no more or less convenient than a destructor.